# USB Host Shield plus 2 identical joysticks

Tags: usb, joystick

I'm trying to get two identical joystics (Saitek cyborg 3D) running with the USB-Host-Shield on a Mega 2560 and an USB-Hub.

I already get the event-messages of both of them:

```
#include <usbhid.h>
#include <hiduniversal.h>
#include <usbhub.h>

// Satisfy IDE, which only needs to see the include statment in the ino.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>

#include "hidjoystickrptparser.h"

USB Usb;
USBHub Hub(&Usb);
HIDUniversal Hid1(&Usb);    // first Joystick
HIDUniversal Hid2(&Usb);    // second Joystick

JoystickEvents Joy1Events;
JoystickEvents Joy2Events;

JoystickReportParser Joy1(&Joy1Events);
JoystickReportParser Joy2(&Joy2Events);

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
        while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
        Serial.println("Start");

        if (Usb.Init() == -1)
                Serial.println("OSC did not start.");

        delay(200);

        if (!Hid1.SetReportParser(0, &Joy1))
                ErrorMessage<uint8_t > (PSTR("SetReportParser1"), 1);
        if (!Hid2.SetReportParser(0, &Joy2))
                ErrorMessage<uint8_t > (PSTR("SetReportParser2"), 1);
}

void loop() {
        Usb.Task();
        Serial.print("\tX1: ");
        PrintHex<uint8_t > (JoystickEvents::mostRecentEvent.X, 0x80);
        Serial.print("\tY1: ");
        PrintHex<uint8_t > (JoystickEvents::mostRecentEvent.Y, 0x80);
        Serial.print("\tX2: ");
        PrintHex<uint8_t > (JoystickEvents::mostRecentEvent.Z1, 0x80);
        Serial.print("\tY2: ");
        PrintHex<uint8_t > (JoystickEvents::mostRecentEvent.Z2, 0x80);
        Serial.print("\tRz: ");
        PrintHex<uint8_t > (JoystickEvents::mostRecentEvent.Rz, 0x80);
        Serial.println("");

}
```

My question is: How can I distinguish the events from the different joysticks.

I'm trying to get some kind of port-information from the USB-Hub. Unfortunately something like

```
!hid->GetAddress()
```

within the JoystickReportParser doesn't do the job as it always returns 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: look at the hub demo

Comment: That's what I'm doing since several days but I don't get the clue. I get message-events but how do I recognize from which port they do come?

In the hub demo there is this function: PrintAllAddresses() which takes a pointer to the device. But it's called within this statement: Usb.ForEachUsbDevice(&PrintAllAddresses);

Comment: In the hub demo there is this function: PrintAllAddresses() which takes a pointer to the device. But it's called within this statement: Usb.ForEachUsbDevice(&PrintAllAddresses);

So how would I call something like this from within the JoytickReportParser or the eventhandler OnGamepadChanged ?

Comment: Or how do I get a pointer to the device from which a message-event comes in?

Comment: To be honest. I'm not so familiar with all this pointer arithmetic. 
All these -> :: ! * .  Is still a little bit wired to me.

Comment: i am talking about this demo ... https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/examples/hub_demo/hub_demo.ino  .... it looks like it prints a whole bunch of info about every usb device that is plugged in ..... start with that

Comment: the `!` is a boolean `not` statement ... when it is `rainy` it is `!sunny`

Comment: @jstola I'm afraid you statement is incorrect sometimes it is sunny && rainy at the same time.

Comment: logically, that is true, but it was meant as a rough example of the not operator (also my comment is incorrect because the `not` is really a unary operator, not a statement)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @jsotola I already ran this hub-demo. So I know that the two Joysticks are attached to two USP-Ports at the hub, which have addresses like A and B. The output of the PrintAdress() Function is something like (0,1,A) and (0,1,B) for the two Joysticks.
What I do not know is. How can I access this information from within the event-handler-function called void JoystickEvents::OnGamePadChanged(const GamePadEventData *evt) {} from the Joystick-Demo.

Comment: A documentation of the USB-HUB-2.0 Library can be found here: http://felis.github.io/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/inherits.html. (There's a nice class hierarchy at the bottom of the site). From looking there it seems to me that the class USBHID that might be responsible for the Joystickreadouts seems to inherit from the class USBDeviceConfig (or vice versa what would not make sense to me but who knows. Does the direction of the arrows indicate the direction of inheritance in this diagram?)

Comment: So my question is: What line of code would I have to add to the event-handler-function void JoystickEvents:: OnGamePadChanged(const GamePadEventData *evt) {} in hidjoystickrptparser.cpp from the USBHIDJoystick.ino-Demo to get these A and B USB-addresses from my previous comment? So when a message-event comes in I know from which Joystick it comes.

Comment: Or let me put the question in other words. The void JoystickEvents::OnGamePadChanged(const GamePadEventData *evt) {
}-Function gets a pointer to an event-object *evt. This *evt-object must somehow be connected to the USBdevice-object where it comes from. But how can I access this, and how can I figure out which method to call stepping through the inheritance hierarchies to get the address of the USBdevice?

Comment: Or maybe like this: In the hub-demo I find the function:
void PrintAllAddresses(UsbDevice *pdev)
{
  UsbDeviceAddress adr;
  adr.devAddress = pdev->address.devAddress;

  Serial.print(adr.bmAddress, HEX);
  Serial.println(")");
}
So if I could somehow get this handle *pdev from within the event-handler-function from the Joystickdemo, I could imagine to get this address. But unfortunately I do not know how to get this.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same issue. I got already working in the main void loop: Serial.print(Hid1.GetAddress());
But to distinguish the 2 identical joysticks in the event loop, did you already manage -> Palmstroem?

Comment: this could be a possible answer:
https://github.com/Bratski/Arduino-2-Joysticks-to-PPM

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the question that was asked but part of the problem.

This is a simple introduction to pointers.

```
int variable = 42;                              // Create a variable
int* pointer = &variable;                       // Create a pointer to the variable (by getting its address)
*pointer = 99;                                  // Set the address to a new value
printf ("variable has the value %d", variable); // Print 99.
```

`&x` get the address of `x`

`*y` `dereferences` the pointer y, which means it 'turns it back to a variable' (this is simplistic view which isn't really true, but will do for now). 
So you could, if you wanted (which you wouldn't) do this `*&z` which would be the same as doing `z`.

Basically think of `&` and `*` as a pair of complimentary operators like - and + or * and /.  (They aren't operators, but to start with it might help).

The next problem is when you do this

```
SomeFunction(&variable);
```

All function parameters in C/C++ are passed by value by default.  This means the function gets a copy of them not the actual value.  So if you had:

```
void FunctionOne (int val)
{
    val = 99;
}
int val = 4;
FunctionOne(val);
printf("val = %d", val);   // You will see 4 printed.
```

If you pass by reference then you will see 99 printed, to pass by reference you can do it one of two ways.

```
void FunctionTwo (int& valByRef);
void FunctionThree (int* valPointer);
```

`FunctionTwo` only works with C++ (It will work with an Arduino).

`FunctionThree` might cause a segmentation error if NULL is passed in and the function writes to it.

If it helps in my opinion pointers was one of the hardest concepts to grasp in classic C/C++ so don't worry if you don't understand it just have a play with it and see what you can do.

**Calling Methods**

- `object.method()` - Call the function method on the instance called
  object which is of type `X`.
- `object->method()` - Call the function method on the instance called
  object which is a **pointer** of type `X`.
- `object::method()` - call the function method
  which is a static member of class object (static means it doesn't
  change any data within an instance of a class)
- *object->method() - Avoid this like the plague.  It either means `*(object->method())` or `(*object)->method()` to know you would need to look at the type of object and the return type of the function.  Its easier just to bracket it to remove ambiguity.

As for `*object.&method()` I've never come across that one, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. :)

Comment: Those who don't understand pointers are doomed to program in Javascript the rest of their lives.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Good explanation! What confuses me is: Sometimes you can access a property by object.method or by object.object.method then by object::method and object->method or object.&method or *object.&object::method and object.@->/!%&wtf$method and so on. These things were not made for human brains to be understood.

Comment: Are you saying I'm not human? :)
(See edit)
Its learning a new language, and you just have to remember certain rules, the more you use them the more they become ingrained, there is no short cut :(

Comment: Thank you very much. Superhuman!
Any ideas for the original question? I'm inside a signal-handler-function and want to access an attribute of a parent or grand-parent class, but don't know how to find the right method. The documentation at http://felis.github.io/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/class_u_s_b_device_config.html seems to be quite comprehensive. But I don't get the clue.

Comment: !Hid->GetAddress() always returns 0. Maybe I need to do something like *evt.HIDDevice.Hid->GetAddress() but all trials like that lead to compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a possible answer, in Arduino Code, the USB Host Shield 2.0 library is necessary:

```
#include <usbhid.h> 
#include <hiduniversal.h> 
#include <usbhub.h> 

// Logitech Attack 3 HID report 
struct GamePadEventData { 
    uint8_t X, Y, Z1, Z2, Rz; 
} __attribute__((packed)); 

class JoystickEvents { 
    public: virtual void OnGamePadChanged(const GamePadEventData *evt, int joystick); 
}; 

class JoystickReportParser : public HIDReportParser { 
    JoystickEvents *joyEvents; 
    uint8_t joyId; 
    uint8_t oldPad[sizeof(GamePadEventData)]; 
    public: JoystickReportParser(JoystickEvents *evt, uint8_t id) : joyEvents(evt), joyId(id) {} 
    virtual void Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf); 
}; 

void JoystickReportParser::Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf) { 
    if (!is_rpt_id && len == sizeof(GamePadEventData)) { 
        // Checking if there are changes in report since the method was last called
        bool match = (sizeof(oldPad) == len) && (memcmp(oldPad, buf, len) == 0); 
        if (!match && joyEvents) { 
            joyEvents->OnGamePadChanged((const GamePadEventData*)buf, joyId); 
            memcpy(oldPad, buf, len); 
        }
    } 
} 
 
void JoystickEvents::OnGamePadChanged(const GamePadEventData *evt, int joystick) { 
    Serial.print("Joystick "); 
    Serial.print(joystick); 
    Serial.print(": X: "); PrintHex<uint16_t>(evt->X, 0x80); 
    Serial.print(" Y: "); PrintHex<uint16_t>(evt->Y, 0x80); 
    Serial.print(" Z1: "); PrintHex<uint8_t>(evt->Z1, 0x80); 
    Serial.print(" Z2: "); PrintHex<uint8_t>(evt->Z2, 0x80); 
    Serial.print(" Rz: "); PrintHex<uint8_t>(evt->Rz, 0x80); 
    Serial.println(); 
} 

USB Usb; 
USBHub Hub(&Usb); 
HIDUniversal Hid1(&Usb); // first Joystick 
HIDUniversal Hid2(&Usb); // second Joystick 

JoystickEvents JoyEvents; 
JoystickReportParser Joy1(&JoyEvents, 1); 
JoystickReportParser Joy2(&JoyEvents, 2); 

void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(115200); 
        
    Serial.println("Start"); 
    
    if (Usb.Init() == -1) { 
        Serial.println("OSC did not start."); 
    } 
    
    delay(200); 
    
    if (!Hid1.SetReportParser(0, &Joy1) || !Hid2.SetReportParser(1, &Joy2)) { 
        ErrorMessage<uint8_t>(PSTR("SetReportParser"), 1); 
    } 

} 

void loop() {
    Usb.Task(); 
}
```